# What does it mean to 'Find the limit function $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n\; x}$?

Tags: limits, functions

As the question asks, I'm wondering about what it means to:

Find the limit function $$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n\;x}$$

By taking the limit, I can easily see that the exponential decay function basically becomes the bottom left corner of an infinite square but I'm confused as to what exactly it means to find that limit and how the answer would even be written. I'm also assuming that this has something to do with Fourier series but I don't know how.

I hope the question isn't too silly and thank you for any assistance.

Thank you again.

Comment: The function in your title is different from the one in your question. What do you mean by the "corner of an infinite square"?

Comment: By 'corner...' I meant that at $x=0$, there is a vertical line then for $x<0$ the function is simply $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: That is not what the graph of $f$ looks like. For starters, $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant for $x>0$, the function is $f(x) = 0$, I mistyped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, you only need to evaluate the pointwise limit of $e^{-nx}$ as $n\to \infty$.

Then if $x=0$, $e^{-n \cdot 0}=1, f(0)=1$. If $x>0$, $f(x)=\lim_{y\to -\infty}e^{-y}=0$. And if $x<0$, $f(x)=\lim_{y\to \infty}e^{y}=\infty$.